# Block broswer option on Safari Iphone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I have a site but in Iphone device with safari for example there a bar with button in the bottom

Like this: [image]

The image of the right.

And in this site : https://prismic.io/ if you clic on the menu burger this navigation bar is blocked. I want this but I don't know how to do.

If you have an idea ? thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? I've been to the site and the navigation bar isn't blocked, could you post images using the site you've linked to show what you want.

Comment: @GeorgeLee In the site ( on mobile iphone and safari ) if you scroll the page a little to have the bar like in my image of the right and you click on the hamburger button then on button "More" you have severals title like "About" "API tour" "writing room tour" etc ... and if you scroll here the bar is blocked and if you didn't appear this at the beginning, it doesn't appear. That work for you ? Sorry I don't have an iphone at home but at the work so I can post images tomorrow.